# jmeter individual user - controlled test

Tags: jmeter, multi-user

I want to do test with 100 users for 1 hour. i want to control each user individually. I.e. User 1 will be executing script no. 1 during first minute. then he will execute script no. 5 for next minute and so on. similar pattern with other users but with different script no.

Is this feasible with Jmeter ?

I can think of multiple thread group but that will result in creating 150 thread groups, which does not seem correct solution.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to factor out some of common behaviour using ModuleController or IncludeController.
When only data changes, you can use CSV DataSet for different data per user.
But if really you have 100 different scenarios then I think your methodology is wrong.
You should follow Pareto principle and select only the most common used scenarios or the most valuable ones.